# Searchable multiple product select custom field for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I am developing a plugin where I need to display some custom select product. So far I can able to make the option field but how can i save them as option field with comma separated product ids like.

```
45,78,55,48,
```

here is an example of searchable multiple select option for WooCommerce product.

[image]

Here is my code

```
function crp_select_products() {
    global $post, $woocommerce;
    $product_ids = array();
    ?>
    <div class="options_group">
        <?php if ( $woocommerce->version >= '3.0' ) : ?>
            <p class="form-field">
                <label for="related_ids"><?php _e( 'Search Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                <select class="wc-product-search" multiple="multiple" style="width: 50%;" id="related_ids" name="related_ids[]" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search for a product&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-action="woocommerce_json_search_products_and_variations">
                    <?php
                        foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
                            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                            if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
                                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $product_id ) . '"' . selected( true, true, false ) . '>' . wp_kses_post( $product->get_formatted_name() ) . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </select> <?php echo wc_help_tip( __( 'Select products are for sale product.', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Ask more specific. Where do you want to store what, for what purpose?

Comment: @radscheit show this as a plugin option field. so selected product ids can be save as option value with comma separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is something missing in your function, to display the saved data in it.

After, this special field need to be displayed inside a form that will have a submit button. So it depends where you are using your function.

Here below is an example displaying that custom field as a custom product setting, save the data and display the saved data in it:

```
function crp_get_product_related_ids() {
    global $post, $woocommerce;

    $product_ids = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_related_ids', true );
    if( empty($product_ids) )
        $product_ids = array();
    ?>
    <div class="options_group">
        <?php if ( $woocommerce->version >= '3.0' ) : ?>
            <p class="form-field">
                <label for="related_ids"><?php _e( 'Search Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                <select class="wc-product-search" multiple="multiple" style="width: 50%;" id="related_ids" name="related_ids[]" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search for a product&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-action="woocommerce_json_search_products_and_variations">
                    <?php
                        foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
                            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                            if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
                                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $product_id ) . '"' . selected( true, true, false ) . '>' . wp_kses_post( $product->get_formatted_name() ) . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </select> <?php echo wc_help_tip( __( 'Select products are for sale product.', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_custom_fied_in_product_general_fields', 20 );
function add_custom_fied_in_product_general_fields() {
    global $post, $woocommerce;
    crp_get_product_related_ids();
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'process_product_meta_custom_fied', 20, 1 );
function process_product_meta_custom_fied( $product_id ){
    if( isset( $_POST['crosssell_ids'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_related_ids', array_map( 'intval', (array) wp_unslash( $_POST['related_ids'] ) ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. instead of product meta data is it possible to show this as a plugin option field. so selected product ids can be save as option value with comma separated.

Comment: @Firefog Yes i suppose… Your actual question is too vague and you should give more information about the context and the location, more details and more related code. So the best thing is to first try and if needed **ask a new question with the necessary related code that allow to reproduce the problem.**